# how to Rollback DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have written following query and when i execute below query it throws an error 'MSDTC on server 'server' is unavailable.' but it commit the data on local server and does not commit data on remote server.So i don't want to commit the data in both database till query run successfully.o how can i handle it within query?

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;
-- Delete candidate from local instance.
DELETE [DBASE].[OWNER].[TABLENAME]
    WHERE ID= 11;
-- Delete candidate from remote instance.
DELETE [SERVER2].[DBASE].[OWNER].[TABLENAME]
    WHERE ID= 10;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: Are you running this from sql server management studio or are you running it from c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a few parameters to your query.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;
-- Delete candidate from local instance.
DELETE [DBASE].[OWNER].[TABLENAME]
    WHERE ID= 11;
-- Delete candidate from remote instance.
DELETE [SERVER2].[DBASE].[OWNER].[TABLENAME]
    WHERE ID= 10;

IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

And that error ('MSDTC on server 'server' is unavailable.') can be a bitch to fix.
here is a link to fix the [distributet transactions](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2083/troubleshooting-sql-server-distributed-transactions-part-1-of-2/)